# AngularJs filter selected option from other select

Tags: angularjs

I have two arrays. The first array name is titles has titles. The second array name is columns has option values. I repeated the first array. If I choose an option I want to hide selected option from other selects. How can I do?

```
$scope.titles = [
    {id: 1, name: 'A1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'A2'},
    {id: 3, name: 'A3'},
    {id: 4, name: 'A4'}
];        

$scope.columns = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Title'},
    {id: 2, name: 'City'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Town'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Nh'}
];

$scope.setColumn = function (id, type) {
    for (var a = 0; a < $scope.columns.length; a++) {
        if ($scope.columns[a].name == type) {
            $scope.titles[id].selectedId = $scope.columns[a].id;
            $scope.titles[id].selectedValue = $scope.columns[a].name;
            $scope.columns[a].selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 mt-5" data-ng-repeat="i in titles">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="s1" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">{{i.name}}</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select ng-options="item.name for item in columns"
                    class="form-control"
                    ng-model="selectedItem"
                    ng-change="setColumn(i.id, selectedItem.name);">
                <option value="">Set options</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or when working with third-party library callbacks.

Comment: New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the [data hiding] problem often shows up when these directives are involved. This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your `ng-models`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to inputs inside an `ng-repeat` is to bind the input to the iterator:

```
<div class="col-md-4 mt-5" data-ng-repeat="i in titles" 
     ng-init="titleIndex = $index">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="s1" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">{{i.name}}</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <select ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in columns"
                    class="form-control"
                    ng-model="i.selectedColumnId"
                    ng-change="setColumn(titleIndex, i)">
                <option value="">Set options</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This allows the controller to control the selection for each `<select>` input.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but here for example when I chooise 'Title' I want to hide other select options